# Fuseki 2 FROM clause

Tags: sparql, fuseki

I successfully set up Fuseki 2 and uploaded an owl file with some triples in to a dataset called **fuseki_test**.

I can use **http://localhost:3030/fuseki_test/query** to successfully run this query:

```
SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object
WHERE {
  ?subject ?predicate ?object
}
```

I would like to use a FROM clause, like this:

```
SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object
FROM </fuseki_test>
WHERE {
  ?subject ?predicate ?object
}
```

but I get no triples back.

What is the proper FROM clause on Fuseki 2?

Comment: what is `/fuseki_test`? Another Fuseki service? IF so, please read about [SPARQL 1.1 Federated queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-federated-query/) - And you'll need the full URI to the SPARQL endpoint. The keyword `FROM` is just to specify the default graph: https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#specifyingDataset

Comment: /fuseki_test is the dataset.  My example is very simple, but I often want models and data sources in different datasets and use multiple FROM clauses to query the appropriate data.  I can't seem to make this work yet in fuseki.

Comment: General comment: `</fuseki_test>` is not an absolute URI and the URI will be resolved by parsing. It is possible to check the names in the dataset with `SELECT * { GRAPH ?g {} }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between a dataset and a graph.

Following [SPARQL specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#specifyingDataset), `FROM` clause is used to specify the particular graph considered in the query within a dataset. By default, all triples are generated within the `default` graph.

On the other side, a dataset within FUSEKI can be a collection of graphs. In general, it is composed of a `default` graph among others.

In your case, `fuseki_test` is a dataset, not a graph so `FROM` is not relevant. Clue is you can access the dataset through `http://localhost:3030/fuseki_test/query`.

Comment: Yes.  I had understood these, but tripped over little differences in terminology in the API with Fuseki2, Virtuoso, and Neptune.  I had indeed confused graph and dataset when I uploaded the data using Fuseki.  I had entered "fuseki_test" for both the dataset and graph the first time I tried the Fuseki data uploader.  In retrospect it is very clear.  Thanks.